# Polling on android map from webservice

Tags: android, android-maps

I am doing map application in Android with polling functionality - i.e. I have webservice which giving customers current lat/lang position.

So I need to show it on map with marker. For that I need to call web service every 30 seconds and get current lat/lat values and display it on the map. I have tried timer but the entire page is getting refreshed so my screen flickers. I need to update lat/lang position alone - not the entire screen. Can anybody guide me in this? Examples are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PUSH messaging instead of polling. It is inefficient way of handling realtime update of movements on map. Whenever you have update of (lat,long) of a customer, you need to push to the device and ask the device to update its marker on the map.

[Android PUSH messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: U mean PUSH notifications? If so, i dont want to do that.Any other way?